# c char ** causing allocation error

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, access-violation

I am passing a multidimensional character array to a function in c. The main() or whatever function determines the size (dimensions) of the input array. I am trying to determine the length and width of the array dynamically in my function. So far, I have been able to determine the width dynamically for the first row. However, if I try to use the same logic to determine the length, I am getting access violation error. This is the code I have so far:

```
char * myfunc( char* in[] )
{
    int index=0, cols=0;
    while( in[0][index++] != '\0' );
    cols = index - 1;
    :
    :
}

int main()
{
     char *in[3] = {"abcd","efgh","ijkl"};
     char *out   = myfunc( in );
     :
     :
}
```

Luckily for me, 'cols' in all 'rows' of the **in are equal. I understand a more robust approach will be to first determine the number of rows and test the number of cols for each row there after. I am causing an access violation error every time I try to do something similar for the rows.

I should mention, I cannot redefine the function to pass the dimensions of the array. I should also mention, this is not homework or work-work, I came across this problem while brushing my c coding skills. Is there a way to determine the number of rows in the case above without causing an access violation error?

Comment: For starters, that should be `const char *in[3]`. Those are literal constants. So should your parameter declaration be as well.

Comment: I really don't control the function that calls this function. That is a challenge.

Comment: You don't need to control the caller. The caller can pass non-const strings if they want to. But unless you're planning on modifying them, or passing them to a function that will, there is no reason *not* to declare the incoming pointers *here* as const. The caller will be fine. Were it the other way around (caller invoking with `const` pointers and you requiring non-const) you would have an issue, but I don't see that case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char * myfunc( char* in[] )
{
    int rows;
    for(rows = 0; in[rows]; ++rows)
        ;
    printf("%d\n", rows);

    .....
    .....
}

int main()
{
     char *in[] = {"abcd",, "efgh","ijkl", NULL};
     char *out   = myfunc( in );
}
```

It's worthwhile detecting columns only if all strings are of the same length.

Comment: I did take your suggestions - added the NULL and executed for( rows=0; in[rows];++rows ) to get the correct result. I am then determining if the width of each row is same - a requirement.

However, I also tried for( rows=0; in[rows];++rows ) without using the NULL. Interestingly, for my original input - {"abcd","efgh","ijkl"} the rows count=10. If I add "mnop" to the input array, rows=11, adding "qrst" give rows=13. I changed "abc", and so on and I still get the same result. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: @BigLib - the for loop stops when it finds a NULL (0). It's randomly happening at the 10th element or 11th element & hence it stops there. However, you get into the zone of undefined behaviour and hence should be avoided. You should use the for loop I gave if and only if the last element is initialized to NULL.

Comment: Yeah, I just kept trying new inputs to see if the behavior persists. I changed the number of characters - columns - in each row. The relation seems proportional to the number of rows only. It does not seem random. But I have to agree with you. I have, at most, anecdotal evidence of this behavior. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 2):

With the data you have, it can't be done.  But you could add a sentinel like this:

```
char *in[4] = {"abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", NULL};
```

and then look for the sentinel (which is effectively what you're doing to count the columns, by looking for the sentinel `'\0'` in the first string).